# using subquery to get information for main query

Tags: mysql, subquery

So I have this first query that works well:

```
$sql = "SELECT mbr_id, exp_bill, plan_id FROM plan_state WHERE exp_bill <= ((NOW() - INTERVAL 60 DAY)) AND (plan_id BETWEEN 5 AND 11) ORDER BY `plan_state`.`exp_bill` DESC";
```

But I need to combine it with this one:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name_first, name_last, language FROM member WHERE id = mbr_id";
```

(mbr_id comes from the first query.)

I tried a few subqueries but can't make it work.

Then I would need to echo the results.

Thanks!  Any help appreciated!

Comment: you need a join not a subquery.  Read up on joins in this venn diagram approach to joins explainations: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Thanks.  I can see that I need a FULL OUTER JOIN.  @xQbert  I need to use the records from one with records from the other.  Thanks for the example and link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example

```
SELECT ps.mbr_id
     , ps.exp_bill
     , ps.plan_id
     , m.id
     , m.name_first
     , m.name_last
     , m.language 
FROM Plan_State ps
INNER JOIN Member m
 on PS.mbr_ID = m.Id
WHERE ps.exp_bill <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 60 DAY)
  AND ps.plan_id BETWEEN 5 AND 11
ORDER BY ps.exp_bill DESC
```

Now if you need all records from plan_state and those related in Member use a `left join` in place of `inner join`.  If you need all records from member and only those that match in plan state then use a `Right join` instead of a `inner join`  However, you use a right join, the where clause criteria will have to be moved to the join to retain the unmatched records from member.

'ps' and 'm' are table alias which cut down on fully qualified column names and generally improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

Use a join:

```
SELECT member.id, name_first, name_last, language
FROM member
INNER JOIN plan_state
    ON member.id = plan_state.mbr_id
WHERE exp_bill <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 60 DAY) AND plan_id BETWEEN 5 AND 11
/* group by/order by, etc */
```

Keep in mind of how join behaves, if you have multiple rows in `plan_state` (B) which would match in `member` (A), then you'll end up with essentially "duplicated" row outputs for table A, with the uniques from table B joined to those "duplicate" rows.